# unable to create date from format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+00:00"

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I want to convert from string to date.
Am I using the correct format here with  *"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+00:00"*?

```
extension String {
    func format(_ format:String) -> String {
        var date: Date?
        let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
        let dateFormatterOutput = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+00:00"
        dateFormatterOutput.dateFormat = format
        if let d = dateFormatterGet.date(from: self) {
            date = d
        }
        return dateFormatterOutput.string(from: date!)
    }
}

extension Date {
    func string(with format: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Annnndddd, what's you're input? What's your question?

Comment: Why are you using +00:00 in the date format?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the line:

```
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+00:00"
```

`+00:00` needs to be replaced with `xxxx` such as:

```
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx"
```

Your code will become:

```
func format(_ format:String) -> String {
    var date: Date?
    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    let dateFormatterOutput = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx"
    dateFormatterOutput.dateFormat = format
    if let d = dateFormatterGet.date(from: self) {
        date = d
    }
    return dateFormatterOutput.string(from: date!)
}
```

**Note**: Here I am assuming that the date string you are using will contain the time zone as **+xx:xx (such as +02:00)** and so on. However, for a different format, you need to use different number of `x` (small `x` is used if the timezone does not contain Z):

1. `x` -> -08, +0330
2. `xx` -> -0800
3. `xxx` -> -800, -075254
4. `xxxx` -> -8:00, -07:52:54

In case the timezone contains `Z`, then we use capital `X`.